# Connecting to LocalDB Server in Navicat Premium

Tags: sql-server, localdb, sql-server-2016-localdb

Recently I installed LocalDb Serer on my laptop. I am trying to establish a connection between Navicat and LocalDB server. But unable to get the correct Host Name/IP Address for the LocalDB server. 
I noticed by default LocalDB server always creates an instance named MSSQLLocalDB when started.
I've searched internet but couldn't find the exact solution for my problem in navicat premium software. Here is the error I am getting. 

Excuse me if I've posted this in the wrong forum. 

[image: error]

**EDIT** 
 After some try I am getting this error. I don't think there is anything wrong in the instance name. [image: error new]

Comment: Why dont you follow the suggestions from the Message?

Comment: I did have LocalDB server installed on my pc. Is it not a SQL Server Native client?

Comment: No, LocalDB is a "service" - download ENU\x64\sqlncli.msi from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676

Comment: Thank you. Installing a native 2012 SQL Server client did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the Native SQL Client, as the error message suggests.

Download ENU\x64\sqlncli.msi from www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676